# What happens if I create a process that already exists in the task manager?

Tags: windows-7, windows, process, task-manager, c#

I am developing an application in C # with the assembly name of one of the windows processes like **svchost.exe, taskmgr.exe, winlogon.exe**, etc. And I would like to know if this could cause some conflict with windows. My application is basically to prank a friend and I would like the user to not close it from the task manager. For this reason I want to put the name as one of the windows processes.

**Any idea if this can cause problems? Any other suggestion of how to hide my application in windows?**

Comment: It will be listed twice.  Task Manager likely will take it upon itself to make the name unique.  What does your testing show?

Comment: There is no requirement that process names be unique. Duplicate process names are a routine occurrence, such as with svchost.exe. Process names are there largely for the convenience of users and Windows cares for them only in that they are part of the process path. Windows identifies processes by their PID which will always be unique. It is assigned to the process by the kernel on creation

Comment: Very interesting LMiller7. Thank you for the explanation :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have as many processes with the same name as you have resources to run them, each process will have it's own unique PID (Process ID) however which I don't believe you have any control over.